# How to get access to command-line arguments in Nim?

Tags: command-line-arguments, nim-lang

How can I access command line arguments in Nim?

The documentation shows only how to run the compiled Nim code with command line arguments

```
nim compile --run greetings.nim arg1 arg2
```

but I didn't find how to use their values in code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is an example that prints the number of arguments and the first argument:

```
import std/os

echo paramCount(), " ", paramStr(1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Personally I find [`paramCount`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#paramCount) and [`paramStr`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#paramStr%2Cint) a bit confusing to work with, because the `paramCount` value differs from C conventions (see the document links).

Fortunately, there are additional convenient functions which do not require to be aware of the conventions:

- [`commandLineParams`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#commandLineParams) returns a `seq` of only command line params.
- [`getAppFilename`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#getAppFilename) returns the executable file name (what is `argv[0]` in the C world).

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked when it was added, but the [parseopt](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parseopt.html) seems to me, the default and the best way for this.

`commandLineParams` isn't available on Posix.

Answer (score 0):

`os.commandLineParams()` returns a sequence of command-line arguments provided to the program.

`os.quoteShellCommand(<openArray[string]>)` takes a sequence of command-line arguments and turns it into a single string with quotes around items containing spaces, so the string can be parsed properly.

`parseopt.initOptParser(<string>)` takes a full command-line string and parses it, returning an `OptParser` object.

`parseopt.getopt(<OptParser>)` is an iterator that yields parsed argument info.

You can combine them to parse a program's input arguments:

```
import std/[os, parseopt]

proc writeHelp() = discard
proc writeVersion() = discard

var positionalArgs = newSeq[string]()
var directories = newSeq[string]()

var optparser = initOptParser(quoteShellCommand(commandLineParams()))
for kind, key, val in optparser.getopt():
  case kind
  of cmdArgument:
    positionalArgs.add(key)
  of cmdLongOption, cmdShortOption:
    case key
    of "help", "h": writeHelp()
    of "version", "v": writeVersion()
    of "dir", "d":
      directories.add(val)
  of cmdEnd: assert(false) # cannot happen

echo "positionalArgs: ", positionalArgs
echo "directories: ", directories
```

Running this with `nim c -r main.nim -d:foo --dir:bar dir1 dir2 dir3` prints:

```
positionalArgs: @["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]
directories: @["foo", "bar"]
```